# How many connections do I have on bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoind

How do I find out how many connections `bitcoind` has made? From terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
bitcoin-cli getnetworkinfo
```

It will tell you, among other things, how many connections you have at the moment.